# Android - Get the String value of R.string.x from a generic java class

Tags: java, android

I created an ArrayList of custom objects that I need for my App. Since the list is really long (ca. 350 elements) I decided to create a separate java class which has the `createList` and the `getList` method:

```
public ArrayList<obj> getList(){
    return obj;
}
```

which I need to get the list from my `MainActivity`.

My custom object looks like this:

```
new Obj(int[] images, String name)
```

I can't seem to be able to import the name from `strings.xml` since this class is not an Activity and does not have a context.

I tried with

```
Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.c)
```

but I get a

> ResourcesNotFound Exception

Is there a way to do it? on top of that I also need to concatenate more strings into one name.

I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't seem to be able to import the name from strings.xml since this class is not an Activity and does not have a context.

Provide a suitably-scoped `Context` to the `Obj` constructor. Or, provide the strings themselves to the `Obj` constructor, where the strings are resolved from their resource IDs by a `Context`.

> I tried with `Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.c)` but I get a `ResourcesNotFoundException`

That is because `getSystem()` returns a `Resources` for the system, which only knows about `android.R` resources, at best.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, why can't I use getApplicationContext()?

Comment: Yes, you can use application context which will know about your application context.

Comment: @Daniele: "why can't I use getApplicationContext()?" -- I can't answer that. For your purposes, that should be fine.